# HTML Table export with jsPDF not responsive

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

why my table in pdf file like this ? i really confused about this.

[table in pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pprwr.png)

[table in html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CveXi.png)

package used: [jsPDF](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF)

function for generate pdf

```
function generatePdf() {
    var doc = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "a4");

    var pdfjs = document.querySelector("#toPDF");
    
    doc.html(pdfjs, {
      callback: function (doc) {
        doc.save("output.pdf");
      },
    });
  }
```

table code

```
<table class="w-full mt-1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th>Jenis Saham</th>
      <th>Pemilik</th>
      <th>Jumlah Saham</th>
      <th>Persentase Saham (%)</th>
      <th>Nilai (dalam Rupiah)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="w-full text-center">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>asd</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>Rp. 100</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

i expect normal table

[expect result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EN8St.png)

Comment: Can you share your id="toPDF" html element? Is it just the table?

Comment: not just table, table inside nested <div />

Comment: Can you share the rest of your code (HTML, CSS, relevant JS) with us? There might be something in your CSS or HTML which is not quite compatible with jsPDF. Also, do you get any errors when you try to validate your HTML in an external / online validator?

Comment: i used just Tailwind css

Comment: Do you include tailwind css in jsPDF?